# I want to understand how to use aws start_session output to execute commands

Tags: python, websocket, boto3, aws-ssm, aws-session-manager

I am using python and AWS boto3 to automate a few manual works. My Scenario is once I open a session with the session manager I will be able to execute commands like connecting to my DB.

Now I used boto3 start_session where I got the response with TokenValue, StreamURL but I am not sure how to executes commands using this. Please help,

```
response = client.start_session(
    Target='string',
    DocumentName='string',
    Parameters={
        'string': [
            'string',
        ]
    }
)
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You want to use _client.send_command()_